# Заключение в кавычки подлинных выражений 3

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

Кто преодолеет указанные сложности и стереотипы первым, кто раньше других повысит энергоэффективность своего производства, а значит, снизит производственные издержки и себестоимость продукции (т. е. фактически повысит свою конкурентоспособность), тот, при прочих равных условиях, не только упрочит свои позиции на рынке, но и получит новый, мощный импульс развития! Говоря словами известного советского кинохита, информацию к размышлению, господа предприниматели!

Нужны ли здесь кавычки у слов "информацию к размышлению"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Говоря словами известного советского кинохита, "информацию к размышлению", господа предприниматели!

В этих  случаях дословное высказывание заключается в кавычки, а  вводные слова указывают на источник цитирования, например: По словам Репина, « вдохновение – это награда за каторжный труд».

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Да, кавычки тут нужны.

Но уж очень неудачная конструкция. С одной стороны "словами китнохита", с другой - "господа предприниматели". После такого начала, вся оставшаяся часть фразы воспринимается как "слова кинохита", во всяком случае - до конца законченного фрагмента. Обращение же (даже к предпринимателям) после такого начала как-то совсем не к месту. Я, будь моя воля, упоминание источника убрал бы вовсе (и так все знают), а кавычки оставил.

Comment: Да, у меня тоже сначала возникло такое ощущение...